# Html Form Web Part - what is the corresponding class?

Tags: web-part, splimitedwebpartmanager

I need to add a HTML Form Web Part to a SharePoint 2010 page programmatically in a feature receiver, but I can't find the class to instantiate.

Answer (score 1):

It's Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SimpleFormWebPart

You'll also need to embed this somehow:

```
  <sfwp:Content xmlns:sfwp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/SimpleForm">

<![CDATA[<div onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) _SFSUBMIT_"><input type="text" name="T1"/><input type="button" value="Go" onclick="javascript:_SFSUBMIT_"/></div>]]></sfwp:Content>
```

Comment: I do i get the value of T1? In an alert or something
As i want to make sure my params date are correct.
Chhers